# Can I disable system keys via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I want to disable system keys (for example, the Win Key) on my images? Is it possible?

Comment: What can you do with the Windows key on an image in the first place?

Comment: I dont want Save As Image button.

Comment: Better place some overlay over image. That will stop most of users from saving your images.

Comment: Understand that there's no complete way to prevent a user from saving an image.  At the very least, they can take a screenshot.  Think about it... "I want to send this image to the user's computer, but I don't want the user's computer to have this image."  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: as always: IF YOU WANT TO PROTECT YOUR IMAGES - DON'T EXPOSE THEM ON THE INTERNET!!!!11! The moment somebody sees them in his browser, they already "downloaded" your precious precious images.

Comment: , whatever you do, You can't prevent the user to take a screenshot

Comment: @user1213807: An overlay would just be a transparent `div` or something of that nature, styled by CSS to be "on top of" the target image.  This would essentially prevent right-click in the browser window.  But, as we've said, the user _has_ downloaded the image at this point anyway.

Comment: @hogni89 or to print the image or to disable javascript or to get the image from the browsercache or to let the browser circumvent the attempt to prevent the context-menu or one of the other 500 methods to work around the poor tries to protect your image.

Comment: Somewhat related anecdote: A client of mine once spent a lot of money building an interface (not web) that would display a document but not allow the user to save it.  It hooked into the OS, ran in a special shell, etc.  They had a business requirement that users can see this document live, but absolutely legally are forbidden to have a copy of it, otherwise the company could be sued into oblivion.  When they proudly demonstrated this functionality to me, the first thing I did, much to their dismay, was take out my phone and snap a picture of the screen.  Money well spent, indeed.

Comment: OP was not spouting complete nonsense. It does "make sense" (setting philosophical debate aside) to want to attempt to protect proprietary images from breach of copyright/unlawful duplication; software has been developed for this purpose. Search for "domain lock image piracy"

Comment: @Tim you're not affiliated to that company, are you? Because that is complete nonsense.

Comment: @David owned;) you're the boss.

Comment: In fact, there are a lot of expensive content management systems out there, as @David says - Some of them allowing the user to use a "expire" date on the document and so on.

But the user can always take a screendump, or snap a photo

Comment: @Christoph: I have no affiliation whatsoever with any company in that market niche. The word "that" in your comment lacks a clear antecedent.

Comment: Dear friends, i want only disable sistem keys. I know, can't prevent screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode); // replace "37" below with the windows key code
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "windows key pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: you can't prevent system-keys.

Comment: Makes sense. I just provided the answer if it worked... don't use windows.

Comment: besides the fact, that this is a useless attempt to protect images.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.
Try this http://jsfiddle.net/XBHp7/

```
​$(document.body)​.keypress(function( e ){
     document.body.innerHTML += e.which + "<br/>";
});​
```

As you can see, the webpage in the browser will not recognize the windows key as a keypress.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect those key strokes (depending on the browser) but not prevent the system to get them.

Here's a list of standard key codes with a mechanism to get the other ones : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

For exemple on Chrome/Ubuntu, I can see when the user press the win key (code 91 on my system) but not prevent the action the system maps to it.